# Python: индекс списка вне допустимого диапазона

Tags: python, python-3.x, index, scapy

Пытаюсь провести сканирование сервера, путем отправления на него SYN-пакетов. Но при запуске получаю довольно известную ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Synscaner.py", line 19, in <module>
    ip = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of rang
```

Появляется она при неизвестных обстоятельствах, так как код я проверил и грубых ошибок не нашел. Пытался заменить эту строчку поставив в нее реальные адреса. Но итог по прежнему тот же. Код самой программы описан ниже со всеми комментариями. Заранее спасибо за решение проблемы.

```
from scapy.layers.inet import ICMP, IP, TCP, sr1
import sys


def icmp_probe(ip):     # Здесь производится проверка на наличие сервера в сети.
    icmp_packet = IP(dst=ip) / ICMP()   
    resp_packet = sr1(icmp_packet, timeout=10)      # Отправка и прием одного пакета
    return resp_packet != None


def syn_scan(ip, port):     # В данном месте проводится сканирование путем отправки пакетов.
    syn_packet = IP(dst=ip) / TCP(dport=port, flags="S")
    resp_packet = sr1(syn_packet, timeout=10)
    if resp_packet.getlayer('TCP').flags == 0x12 and resp_packet !=None:   # Проверка на флаги SYN/ACK
         print(f"Port open: {ip}:{port}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = sys.argv[1]
    port = sys.argv[2]
    if icmp_probe(ip):
        syn_ack_packet = syn_scan(ip, port)
        syn_ack_packet.show()
    else:
        print("ICMP Probe Failed")
```

Comment: как понимаю, sys.argv[1] - первый  аргумент в командной строке. Тогда ошибка означает, что его там нет в необходимый момент. Но как она может появляться при замене на реальное значение?? Строка `ip = 192.198.000.001` выдает ошибку  `list index out of rang`???

Comment: @Сергей опечатка вышла. При реальных значениях, допустим в поле ip поставим 127.0.0.1 а переменной port зададим значение 21 программа будет работать. Но я не понимаю почему она не хочет принимать значение sys.argv[1]

Comment: тогда см. мой ответ выше. вообще не понимаю, как всё это работает и зачем (в смысле, что не анализировал), но логика простая. Вопрос: почему вы уверены, что в командной строке всё время есть что-то вам нужное? Можете поставить `print` перед этой командой и ловить момент генерации ошибки. Или вообще прерывание IndexError обрабатывайте, если там масса хлама повалится на печать.

Comment: Попробую заменить значения на реальные и тогда уже перехватывать ошибку AttributeError. Тогда решение должно быть гораздо легче.

Comment: и, кстати, ключевой вопрос (можете себе ответить, а не мне:-))- а что для вас "решение проблемы"?

Comment: Для меня решение проблемы это избавление от ошибки, а это замена переменных ip и port на реальные значения. + если я добьюсь полностью рабочего кода (а этот фикс приводит лишь к новой ошибке), то он будет выложен в ответ на этот вопрос

Comment: я бы сказал: "этот фикс позволил продвинуться дальше и решать следующую проблему":-)

Comment: Не важно, что выполняет ваша программа. Главное, что она "рушится" на первом же (!!)  операторе, который пытается выполнить - ip = sys.argv[1]. Это говорит только о том, что элемента sys.argv[1] нет. (У этой ошибки и причины другой при положительном значении индекса нет согласно документации).  Покажите, как оно (значение) туда (первый параметр скрипта)  попадает?

Comment: @Wacihil а запускаете его как? желательно пример запуска скриншотом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корень этой проблемы заключался в неправильной адресации цели для которой выполнялось сканирования. Чтобы исправить ситуацию следует указать реальный IP адрес в виде переменной типа string и также создать массив, в котором будут храниться порты для сканирования. На деле готовый и рабочий код выглядит следующим образом.

```
from scapy.layers.inet import ICMP, IP, TCP, sr1


def icmp_probe(ip):  # Здесь производится проверка на наличие сервера в сети
    icmp_packet = IP(dst=ip) / ICMP()
    resp_packet = sr1(icmp_packet, timeout=10)  # Отправка и прием одного пакета
    return resp_packet is not None


def syn_scan(ip, ports):  # В данном месте проводится сканирование путем отправки пакетов
    for port in ports:      # Проходимся по каждому порту и отправляем TCP пакет
        syn_packet = IP(dst=ip) / TCP(dport=port, flags="S")
        resp_packet = sr1(syn_packet, timeout=10)
        if resp_packet is not None:
            if resp_packet.getlayer('TCP').flags == 0x12:
                print(f"{ip}:{port} is open")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ip = "127.0.0.1"    # Задаем цель сканирования
    ports = [20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 43, 53, 80,    # Обозначаем порты для сканирования
            115, 123, 143, 161, 179, 443, 445,
            514, 515, 993, 995, 1080, 1194,
            1433, 1723, 3128, 3268, 3306, 3389,
            5432, 5060, 5900, 8080, 10000]
    try:    # Перехватываем исключения в момент, когда заканчивается кортеж (наш список портов)
        if icmp_probe(ip):
            syn_ack_packet = syn_scan(ip, ports)
            syn_ack_packet.show()
        else:
            print("ICMP Probe Failed")
    except AttributeError:
        print("Scan completed!")
```